# How to use Samsung Audio SDK to redirect sound from mic to 3.5mm headphone jack?

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to create a service, without UI to redirect sound from microphone to headphone jack, using Samsung audio SDK: http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/professional-audio

At the moment, this code successfully finds microphones and headphones, but I can't hear anything on my headphones. There isn't a lot of examples of this SDK so I am having hard time in understanding, what else do I need to do, to make it work. I need the audio to pass through with as little latency as android device itself allows. Maybe someone could suggest another SDK, or how to have realtime audio pass through?
this is my current code:

```
public class MainActivityBck extends Activity {
    public static String string = null;
    SapaPortConnection sapaPortConnection = null;
    Activity activity = null;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new HeadsetStatusClass();

    private boolean initializedSapaBoolean = true;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = null;
    Sapa sapa = null;
    SapaService sapaService = null;
    SapaProcessor sapaProcessor = null;

    class HeadsetStatusClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG")) {
                switch (intent.getIntExtra("state", -1)) {
                    case 0:
                        WriteToDebugLog.write("DEBUG", "headphone unplugged");
                            Log.d("headphones", "disconnected");
                    case 1:
                            Log.d("headphones", "connected");
                            setVolume(12);

                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")) {

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF") && sapaProcessor != null){

            }
        }
    }

    private void setVolume(int i) {
        if (this.sapaProcessor != null) {
            int i2 = (i * 2) - 27;
            if (i2 >= -27 && i2 <= 3) {
                WriteToDebugLog.write("DEBUG", "sendVolume: volume" + i + "/ nativeVolume: " + i2);
                try {
                    this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/volume:" + i2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    WriteToDebugLog.write("DEBUG", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void setEffectSapa() {
        if (this.sapaProcessor != null) {
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/seteffecttype:" + 0);
        }
    }

    private void setCustomFiltersSapa() {
        if (this.sapaProcessor != null) {
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/finaldelay:" + 0);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/finalfeedback:" + 50);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/drymix:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/wetmix:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdelay:" + 100);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subfeedback:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdecay:" + 30);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdelay2:" + 0);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subfeedback2:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdecay2:" + 30);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdelay3:" + 115);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subfeedback3:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdecay3:" + 30);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdelay4:" + 120);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subfeedback4:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdecay4:" + 30);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdelay5:" + 130);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subfeedback5:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdecay5:" + 20);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdelay6:" + 160);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subfeedback6:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/subdecay6:" + 10);
        }
    }

    private void SetTremoloSapa() {
        if (this.sapaProcessor != null) {
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/tremolo_wet_mix:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/tremolo_dry_mix:" + 40);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/tremolo_frequency:" + 500);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/tremolo_depth:" + -12);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/tremolo_waveform:" + 0);
        }
    }

    private void setPhaserSapa() {
        if (this.sapaProcessor != null) {
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/phaser_drymix:" + 40.0f);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/phaser_sweep_gain:" + 10.0f);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/phaser_center_frequency:" + 10000.0f);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/phaser_depth:" + 5.0f);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/phaser_resonance:" + 7.0f);
            this.sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/phaser_sweep_frequency:" + 10.0f);
        }
    }

    private void ShowSapaAlertDialogAndCloseApp() {
        Log.d("FATAL ERROR", "FATAL ERROR");
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        WriteToDebugLog.write("DEBUG", "onCreated");
        this.activity = this;
        this.sapa = new Sapa();
        try {
            sapa.initialize(this);
            initializedSapaBoolean = true;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            initializedSapaBoolean = false;
            WriteToDebugLog.write("Fatal exception", e2.toString());
            finish();
        }

        try {
            sapaService = new SapaService();
            if (!sapaService.isStarted()){
                sapaService.start(SapaService.START_PARAM_DEFAULT_LATENCY);
            }
            try {
                    sapaProcessor = new SapaProcessor(activity, null, new SapaProcessor.StatusListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onKilled() {
                            Log.d("Sapa Processor", "SapaSimpleClient will be closed. because of the SapaProcessor was closed");
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    sapaService.register(sapaProcessor, false);
                    sapaProcessor.activate();

                    setVolume(12);
                    setEffectSapa();
                    setCustomFiltersSapa();
                    SetTremoloSapa();
                    setPhaserSapa();
                    List arrayList = new ArrayList();
                    List arrayList2 = new ArrayList();
                    try {
                        for (SapaPort sapaPort : sapaProcessor.getPorts()){
                            if (sapaPort.getInOutType() == 1) {
                                arrayList.add(sapaPort);
                            } else {
                                arrayList2.add(sapaPort);
                            }
                        }
                        List playbackDevices = new ArrayList();
                        List captureDevices = new ArrayList();
                        for (SapaPort sapaPort2 : sapaService.getSystemPorts()){
                            if (sapaPort2.getInOutType() == 2 && sapaPort2.getName().contains("playback")) {
                                playbackDevices.add(sapaPort2);
                            } else if (sapaPort2.getInOutType() == 1 && sapaPort2.getName().contains("capture")) {
                                captureDevices.add(sapaPort2);
                            }
                        }
                        if (arrayList.size() >= 2 && playbackDevices.size() >= 2) {
                            sapaService.connect(new SapaPortConnection((SapaPort) arrayList.get(0), (SapaPort) playbackDevices.get(0)));
                            sapaService.connect(new SapaPortConnection((SapaPort) arrayList.get(1), (SapaPort) playbackDevices.get(1)));
                        }
                        if (arrayList2.size() >= 1 && captureDevices.size() >= 2) {
                            sapaPortConnection = new SapaPortConnection((SapaPort) captureDevices.get(0), (SapaPort) arrayList2.get(0));
                            sapaService.connect(sapaPortConnection);
                            WriteToDebugLog.write("DEBUG", "using mic 1");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        ShowSapaAlertDialogAndCloseApp();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                    ShowSapaAlertDialogAndCloseApp();
                    return;
                }
            } catch (Exception e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
                ShowSapaAlertDialogAndCloseApp();
                return;
            }

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

            intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");
            intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
            intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
            registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        sapaProcessor.sendCommand("/start_record:");
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (this.initializedSapaBoolean) {
            unregisterReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver);;
            this.notificationManager.cancelAll();
            if (!(this.sapaService == null || this.sapaProcessor == null)) {
                this.sapaProcessor.deactivate();
                this.sapaService.unregister(this.sapaProcessor);
                this.sapaProcessor = null;
            }
            if (this.sapaService != null && this.sapaService.isStarted()) {
                this.sapaService.stop(false);
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    }
```